# Android RadioButton Color-Change for other Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, colors

I´m new in Android Programming and I have a question for my project.
I want to Change my Background for my Start-Activity (it´s a Reaction Game).
There is an extra activity for all settings (BackgroundColor, Sound etc.),
and I´m lost at this part :/ I want to choose one Color in the Setting-Activity (blue & red), and change the background to the choosen color in the start-Acitivity. Here is the Code for the Activity-Setting, the RadioButtons for the Colors are in one Group (RadioGroup_Color). Does anybody know how to fix this?

I always get an error when I execute this code:

```
public class activity_settings extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_settings);
    colorchange();
}

public void colorchange() {
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup_Color);

    final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);

    final Button button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    button_save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeOption(background);

        }
    });

    final RadioButton changeToBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
    changeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new radioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeToBlue(background);

        }
    });

    final RadioButton changeToRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_red);
    changeToRed.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new radioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeToRed(background);

        }
    });

}

public void changeOption(RelativeLayout background) {
    if (background.isEnabled()) {
        background.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        background.setEnabled(true);

    }
}

public void changeToBlue(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
    background.invalidate();

}
public void changeToRed(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
    background.invalidate();

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

The Error-Message:

```
Error:(38, 91) error: <anonymous com.example.clecks.reaction_game.activity_settings$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in OnCheckedChangeListener
```

**EDIT**

After suggestions and fixes, I still get:

Error:(8, 8) error: com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.

When i click on it there opens a new class named `OnCheckedChangeListener.java`:

```
public class OnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your actual error:

> Error:(38, 91) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in OnCheckedChangeListener

You miss a `onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean)` implementation on a `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Looking at your code I can see two `OnCheckedChangeListener` inplementations; here is one:

```
changeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new radioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        changeToBlue(background);

    }
});
```

**Those implementations are wrong.**

You need to override `onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean)` (`onClick(View)` does not exists in `OnCheckedChangeListener`) as the error reports. Also `new radioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` is wrong and causes the main error.

Fix your code with:

```
changeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton c, boolean b) {
        changeToBlue(background);
    }
});
```

Have a look at the simple official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).

Comment: Thank you, I totally overlooked this line! But now i get another error: Error:(8, 8) error: com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Make sure you changed all implementations. Also, use `new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `new radioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` (which is not abstract) and all should be fine.

Comment: i have changed all implementations... still get the error - don´t know what to to :( link to new code: http://pastebin.com/8s1fXJY9

Comment: I am using your code and it works. What exactly is the current error? Can't be the same one...

Comment: still the same: Error:(8, 8) error: com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener. When i click on it there opens a new class named "OnCheckedChangeListener.java: public class OnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
}

Comment: This must be the same error you made somewhere else. Make a search for `OnCheckedChangeListener`. Again, your code works on my side... can't do much more.